# PHP: Ignore key and extract value of an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function that returns an array where the value is an array like below: I want to ignore the key and extract the value directly. How can I do this without a for loop? The returned function only has one key but the key (2 in this case) can be a variable

```
Array ( [2] => Array ( [productID] => 1 [offerid]=>1)
```

Expected result:

```
Array  ( [productID] => 1 [offerid]=>1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're at least 3 ways of doing this:

Use `current` function, but be sure that array pointer is in the beginning of your array:

```
$array = Array (2 => Array ( 'productID' => 1, 'offerid' => 1));
$cur = current($array);
var_dump($cur, $cur['offerid']);
```

Next is `array_values` function, which will give you array of values with numeric keys, starting with `0`

```
$array = Array ( 2 => Array ( 'productID' => 1, 'offerid' => 1));
$av = array_values($array);
var_dump($av[0], $av[0]['offerid']);
```

And third option is use `array_shift`, this function will return first element of array, but be careful as it reduces the original array:

```
$array = Array ( 2 => Array ( 'productID' => 1, 'offerid' => 1));
$first = array_shift($array);
var_dump($first, $first['offerid']);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the current value of an array, you can use `current()` assuming the array pointer is in the correct position.  If there is only one value, then this should work fine.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

Answer (score 0):

I think Devon's answer will work for you , but if not your can try

`$arr = array_column($arr, $arr[2]);`

if you need always the second index of your master array, if you need all index use

`array_map()`,

something like `array_map('array_map', $arr);` should work.